# need help atleast with the name of the jquery effect

Tags: jquery, html, effect

Hi first and foremost not the type of guy to expect people to hand me the code..I don't mind searching, reading, learning and applying.  But this one I am stumped because I don't know what this effect is called.  [this site](http://decerteau-avocats.eu/) has an awesome effect when you click on the menu the full screen image is covered but in 3 layers? Any help with this I would really appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **View-source** to show the source of the page, then search for occurences of `<script`. If you've found any, filter the possible JQuery plugins (the files usually contain `jquery.`:

Most JS files are minified. Use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to de-minify these files.

Comment: thanks I was able to read their script easier but unfortunatly they did it all meaning they didn't use a plugin already made that I could find a tutorial on.  Not an expert in jquery but guess I'll have to learn it..love a new challenge ;)

Answer (score 0):

[That site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Jpy.png) is using following jquery libraries

[image: http://decerteau-avocats.eu/]